# How do I read the next n bytes from a byte array?

Tags: java, scala

I have loaded a file into a byte array:

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}    
val byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))
```

Now I want to traverse this byte array, in n byte increments like:

1. read first 4 bytes, as an int
2. read next 1 byte, as a bool
3. read next 64 characters, as a UTF8 string.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you explicitly want to read everything in a byte array first? Why not read the file as you'd like "on the fly"? `InputStream` would allow that easily.

Comment: I would recommend checking **Scodec** for manipulating binary data in **Scala**.

Answer (score 4):

Added **Scala version:**

In Scala, you can use the same Java libraries as in Java (example below). The main difference is in syntax, such as the use of val to declare variables. Apart from that, the code is essentially the same as the Java version.

```
val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)

// Read the first 4 bytes as an int
val intValue = buffer.getInt()

// Read the next byte as a boolean
val booleanValue = buffer.get() != 0.toByte

// Read the next 64 bytes as a string
val bytesForStringValue = new Array[Byte](64)
buffer.get(bytesForStringValue)
val stringValue = new String(bytesForStringValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

**Java version:**

If you want to stick with the nio package you can wrap the array in a ByteBuffer

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
```

and then retrieve the values like

```
int intValue = buffer.getInt();
boolean booleanValue = buffer.get() != 0;

byte[] bytesForStringValue = new byte[64];
buffer.get(bytesForStringValue);
String stringValue = new String(bytesForStringValue, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

There are other options though using InputStreams

```
DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file")));
```

and then using the functionality provided by DataInputStream to extract the required values:

```
int intValue = inputStream.readInt();
boolean booleanValue = inputStream.readBoolean();

byte[] bytesForStringValue = new byte[64];
inputStream.readFully(bytesForStringValue);
String stringValue = new String(bytesForStringValue, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: byte buffer or input stream are probably the way to go, since they have a nice built-in way to get integers from bytes, but you should probably translate your answer to scala ;)

Comment: true, I have overlooked that. Thanks!